# How do I create a moving average that takes the average of exactly 5 values, which skips cells that contains zeroes?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I need to calculate the average of exactly 5 values in excel without accounting for cells that contain 0. Using the averageif function (and excluding 0) would only result in 4 numbers being averaged - so the goal is to move on to the next non-zero cell if excel encounters a 0 to only compute the average of 5 non-zero cells. Hope anyone can help

Comment: What does your data look like? What does the expected output look like? What have you tried? [`AVERAGEIFS`](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/averageif-function-faec8e2e-0dec-4308-af69-f5576d8ac642) may likely do what you want.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Are these 5 values a continuous 5 or the first 5 with the largest or smallest extracted

Answer (score 1):

- If your values are in column A, starting at A2
- and if you have Microsoft 365,
- and you want the output in a nearby column

then you can use this formula in `C2` and fill down:

```
=IFERROR(
    LET(
        n, $A$2:A2,
        f, FILTER(n, n <> 0),
        AVERAGE(
            CHOOSEROWS(
                f,
                SEQUENCE(
                    5,
                    ,
                    -1,
                    -1
                )
            )
        )
    ),
    ""
)
```

[image]